# Document root must be a directory RHEL6

Tags: apache, root, document, rhel, rhel6

Respected Members,

I am a newbie to linux. Preparing for my RHCSA exam. I have an error in apache conf which I am unable to solve it. If any member gives me any suggestion regarding this, it will be a great help.

Okay so here is the task which I am trying to perform:
******* YUM Server With HTTP *****

I have copied the whole RHEL6 dvd into my desktop in a directory called "rhelrepo". After that created a database with "createrepo" inside "Packages" folder. Modified httpd server config file with Alias "/repo" pointed towards the directory "/home/admin/Desktop/rhelrepo".

Created directory 

  order allow,deny
  allow from all
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

Disabled selinux, firewall. Restarted the httpd service, it is not accessible. After that I changed the Document root to the appropriate folder /home/admin/Desktop/rhelrepo , it says that "Document Root Must Be A Directory".

I am struggling to find the solutions for this. I have applied the solutions which is provided in this forum but still no luck. Will appreciate any help from the members

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is typically either an SELinux issue or a typo in your configuration. Please check that the documentroot directive does not contain any weird quote characters or full stops or the like. If possible, post your actual DocumentRoot configuration line in this question.

Also, you could run `namei -m /home/admin/Desktop/rhelrepo` to make sure the system sees your directory as an actual directory.